# Builder Design Pattern C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

there is a concept about inheritance which I do not quite understand.
I have a

```
    protected DeveloperReport DeveloperReport; // Field
```

1. Wouldn't PersonalInfoBuilder be able to access that field ?
2. If yes,

   ```
   public PersonalInfoBuilder MyPersonalInfo => new PersonalInfoBuilder(DeveloperReport);
   ```

   Why do I still have to pass the DeveloperReport(field) into PersonalInfoBuilder constructor, when I can
   just modify the protected DeveloperReport field by calling new PersonalInfoBuilder(), instead of 
   new PersonalInfoBuilder(DeveloperReport)?
3. And, how the concept of "return this" return the changes made to DeveloperReport(field) back to
   DeveloperReportBuilder?

Thanks !

```
    class DeveloperReport
    {
        // Properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public DeveloperLevel Level { get; set; }
        public int WorkingHours { get; set; }
        public int HourlyRate { get; set; }

        // Methods
        public double CalculateSalary() => WorkingHours * HourlyRate;
    }

    class DeveloperReportBuilder
    {
        protected DeveloperReport DeveloperReport;

        public PersonalInfoBuilder MyPersonalInfo => new PersonalInfoBuilder(DeveloperReport);

        public DeveloperReportBuilder()
        {
            DeveloperReport = new DeveloperReport();
        }

        // return developer report.
        public DeveloperReport Build() => DeveloperReport;
    }

    class PersonalInfoBuilder : DeveloperReportBuilder
    {
        public PersonalInfoBuilder(DeveloperReport report)
        {
            DeveloperReport = report;
        }

        public PersonalInfoBuilder()
        {

        }

        public PersonalInfoBuilder NameIs(string name)
        {
            DeveloperReport.Name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public PersonalInfoBuilder IDis(int id)
        {
            DeveloperReport.Id = id;
            return this;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only have to pass the report instance if you want to have both instances of `DeveloperReportBuilder` and `PersonalInfoBuilder` have acces to the **same** instance of `DeveloperReport`.

Inheritance will not copy the instance values.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I have got another question. Regarding, "return this", shouldn't the 'this' be refering to the DeveloperReport instance instead of the PersonalInfoBuilder instance ?

Comment: That depends on your intention what the methods should do.